# Union of Cosets as a Subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of finite group $G$ such that $p.|H|<|G|$. Let $x\in G\setminus H$ be an element of order $p$. Under what conditions, the set $H\langle x\rangle = H\cup Hx\cup \cdots Hx^{p-1}$ becomes a subgroup of $G$?

---

(I know that for $H,K\leq G$,  $HK$ is subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK=KH$, and also that if one of the subgroups $H$ and $\langle x\rangle$ is normalized by other, then $H\langle x\rangle$ is subgroup. Any other criteria for proving subgroup?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so called Zappa-Szép product (or Zappa-Szép product) of groups. There is a lot of paper in this topic. Start with Wikipedia.